# Play ringtone along with notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

So, the purpose is to show notification but instead of the default notification sound, ringtone should be played.

I'm using API 28 for testing. I've tried this code but it still plays the default notification sound.

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }

      val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, intent, 0)
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle("Attention request")
            .setContentText(dtext)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            notify(2, builder.build())
        }
```

Also, ringtone should stop playing if user either clicks on notification or dismisses it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, also, now it makes less sense to play ringtone from background, as Android Q implements a much stricter approach to background processing. But I'm actively searching for alternative approaches.